# How can I make image and scatterplot the same height?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing two different subplots. One is an image, another one is a scatterplot.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))

# here I am drawing a greyscale image
image = img.imread(file_name)
fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1).imshow(image, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.axis('off')

# and here I am drawing a scatterplot based on this image.
X, Y = image.shape
x, y = np.nonzero(image)
fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2).scatter(y - Y, -x)
fig.tight_layout()
```

The problem is that when I am drawing them, they have a different height. How can I make the height the same? [image]

Looking for set height matplotlib does not give suitable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as @jure's answer of setting `aspect` (you may also want to try out `equal` rather than `auto`, since `auto` doesn't guarantee the two plots will look the same), you also need to make sure the `xlim` and `ylim` are the same between the two subplots, as it currently looks like both the `x` and `y` range in the `imshow` extend much beyond that of the scatterplot.

Also, as you transform the y and x coordinates, you need set the ranges to `-X, 0` and `-Y, 0`

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as img
import matplotlib.cm as cm


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))

# here I am drawing a greyscale image
image = img.imread(filename)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, aspect='equal')
ax1.imshow(image, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.axis('off')

# and here I am drawing a scatterplot based on this image.
X, Y = image.shape
x, y = np.nonzero(image)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, aspect='equal')
ax2.scatter(y - Y, -x, s=1, linewidths=0)
ax2.set_xlim(-Y, 0)
ax2.set_ylim(-X, 0)
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add keyword `aspect='auto'` to the `imshow` call. So it should look like:

```
fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1).imshow(image, cmap=cm.Greys_r, aspect='auto')
```

From the documentation:

> aspect : [‘auto’ | ‘equal’ | scalar], optional, default: None
>
> If ‘auto’, changes the image aspect ratio to match that of the axes.
>
> If ‘equal’, and extent is None, changes the axes aspect ratio to match that of the image. If extent is not None, the axes aspect ratio is changed to match that of the extent.
>
> If None, default to rc image.aspect value.